# Java Rest Service XML Request syntactically incorrect format

Tags: java, xml, web-services, rest, post

I am new to web services. I am building an android app and I'm trying to send a POST request to the web service but I'm not sure what the correct format is.

This is the POST method in the REST:

```
@POST
@Override
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.TEXT_XML})
public void create(Users entity) {
    super.create(entity);
}
```

These are the atributes is the class that corresponds to our table. I am using Oracle 11g database, Glassfish server 4.1.1 and Netbeans. I am trying to call PUT from my android application. Can someone suggest a way to do that?

```
public class Users implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "USER_ID")
private Short userId;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 30)
@Column(name = "USERNAME")
private String username;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 20)
@Column(name = "PASSWORD")
private String password;

@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 40)
@Column(name = "EMAIL")
private String email;
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "users")
private Profiles profiles;
```

I am trying to call the POST method with the body:

```
`<users> 
<email> user@smth.com</email>
<userid>1</userid>
<password>pass</password>
<username>user</username>
</users>`
```

How should I call it?

Answer (score 0):

you should use JAXB for the serialization of your object or create a string representation of the xml you want to post yourself.
For sending the request use client api from jaxrs https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jaxrs-client001.htm#BABBIHEJ
or if you are using spring RestTemplate

Answer (score 0):

You can use name value pairs as below:

```
    List userdetails = new ArrayList();

    userdetails.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "s@gmail.com"));

    userdetails.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", "1"));

    userdetails.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "5353$$"));

    userdetails.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "shy"));
```

Then post it as below:

```
  // Making HTTP request
        try { 


                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("your url goes here");

                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(userdetails));//params added here

                httpPost.setHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

                InputStream is = httpEntity.getContent();


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }


        try {

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is), 8);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                Log.d("LINE",line);

                sb.append(line + "\n");

            }
            is.close();

            json = sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());

        }


Log.d("RESULT",json);
```

The Post method in your webservice is like below:

```
    @POST
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,MediaType.TEXT_XML,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Path("/insert")
    public Response insertRecord(Users users) {
    }
```

Comment: sample web service implementation here: [link](https://github.com/ktonneh/Jersey2.0AsyncExample)

Comment: I tried adding to the Consumes parenthesis in the POST method MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE, but it doesn't allow me, saying that it cannot be converted to String.